# Foreach 2 var $_POST

Tags: php, html

I have this form:

```html
<form method='post'>
  <input name='i' type='hidden' value='' >
  <input name='email' type='text' >
  <input name='pass' type='password' >
  <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

And the PHP code to print data in a .txt file:

```php
<?php
  $handle = fopen("data.txt", "a");
  foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $variable);
    fwrite($handle, "=");
    fwrite($handle, $value);
    fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
  }
  fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
  fclose($handle);
  exit;
?>
```

The result is:

> i = value
>   email = value
>   pass = value

I don't need to print `$_POST['i']` value.

Any idea?

Comment: Yes, add an IF that tests for `i` and then ignores that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an IF that tests `$variable` for `i` and then ignores that iteration of the loop using a `continue;`

You can also write all the data for each line using one `fwrite`

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
    if ( $variable == 'i' ){
        continue;       // will stop this itereation and continue with the next
    }
    // make one write for all 4 bits of data.
    fwrite($handle, "$variable = $value \r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
```